# Flutter: flutter_local_notifications: invalid_large_icon, The resource justwater could not be found

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-local-notification

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTuhz.png) is the error I am getting.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTuhz.png) is the error I am getting.

I tried this code:

```
const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
```

And I also tried this:

```
const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
```

and this is my folder structure:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f3B1.png)

Does anyone have any thoughts on how/why this error is occurring?